# Why does insertHTML('text') render as "undefined"?

Tags: extjs

When I execute the following extJS code, it shows me "undefined" instead of the text that I want to insert into the div.

[image]

### result

[image]

**How do I insert HTML into my extJS element?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    div#message {
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
  <title>Simple extJS</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = 'ext/resources/images/default/s.gif';
      Ext.onReady(function() {
        console.info('check to see if this shows up in firebug');

        Ext.get('buttonInfo').on('click', function() {
            var message = Ext.get('message');
            message.insertHtml('this is the information');
        });


      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="buttonInfo">Info</button>
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

@flo, if i use `innerHTML` it is not recognized on the extJS object:

[image]

### More attempts that didn't work

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
Sorry, missed important bits of your question.
Don't know extJS, I'm afraid.

I'm still wondering if it wouldn't be simpler just to use the regular DOM, as this seems to be what you're trying to achieve anyway:

```
var x=document.getElementById("message");
x.innerHTML = 'this is the information';
```

Edit2: After a bit of searching, I came up with this:

```
var message = Ext.get('message');
Ext.DomHelper.insertHtml('afterBegin', message, 'this is the information');
```

Edit3: This answer is a mess, but here we go:

```
Ext.DomHelper.insertHtml('afterBegin', message.dom, 'this is the information');
```

or

```
message.update('text');
```

Comment: yes, that would be easier but I need to learn extJS syntax for a project, if they would just provide some examples it would be easier (like jquery does) instead of making developers guess and google until they happen on the sytnax, this doesn't work either even though the documentation indicates it should: Ext.DomHelper.insertHtml('beforeBegin', message, 'insert this');

Comment: to get this finished, I actually just grabbed the element with jQuery and did a jqmessage.html('insert text'); which works as one would expect, no wonder jquery is so popular: it's easy to use

Comment: Kind of confusing syntax for such an apparently simple job, perhaps the choice of the "where" parameter makes this all the difference. I'm not sure. Random guesses on my part will probably just waste your time. :-/

Comment: yes, once I found the where options in the documentation (you have to click it open), then it made sense, I posted the answer here in case anyone runs into this as well

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

```
message.insertHtml('beforeThis', 'insert this');
```

the first parameter can be one of these:

```
beforeBegin, afterBegin, beforeEnd, afterEnd
```

if you want to just change the text, as in jquery .html(), use:

```
message.update('new content');
```